# How to host a native QWidget in .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, qt5

We have a .NET 4.x project and a Qt 5.x project.

We would like to use one or more QWidgets from the Qt project in the .NET project. The widgets would ideally be added to a forms control if possible.

What is the recommended way to solve this issue? One option is to use ActiveX.

Comment: Which of the .NET UI frameworks?

Comment: Primary Windows forms. Possibly WPF if that makes it easier.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent some time working on an application that mixed Win32, WPF, and several flavours of Qt, and you can get it to work although it may make a few of your hairs grey

You can host native controls in a WPF application: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970061(v=vs.100).aspx

Qt can be hosted in native Windows apps using the qtwinmigrate project https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtwinmigrate.  Note - I've only used this to host dialogs, not embed individual controls, so I don't know thats actually a possibility.  I've also had an extremely difficult time getting the messages pipes from all 3 systems to play nicely together, but it is (more or less) possible I think.

The real question is if you have WPF at your disposal, is it really worth getting the Qt in there?  You would need to have a fairly large existing widget to justify the pain.

Comment: Note, our app was originally Win32, then WPF added, then Qt, so its on a different angle to yours.  Hopefully the answer is of some use in pointing you in the right direction though.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. The msdn link is interesting.